# Hovering with moveTo or moveToElement

Tags: nightwatch.js

I'm having trouble getting the background color of a link using the following code and selenium stand-alone 2.53.0 and Firefox  50.0.2661.75 m or Chrome latest:

Although during the test I don't see the mouse moving, at the bottom of the browser's window in the status bar, I do see the URL change to the HREF of the link.

I cannot seem to trigger the hover event for any elements, so the background color is always the default color and not the hovered stated color. Any ideas around this?

```
browser.moveToElement('a[href="http://www.foo.com"]',2,2, function() {
    browser.pause(2000)
           .getCssProperty('a[href="http://www.foo.com"]', "background-color", function(results){
             console.log('color: ' + results);
       });
});
```

If I remove the getCssProperty from the callback, I'm still not getting the right background color for hover and not seeing the mouse pointer move:

```
   browser.moveToElement('a[href="http://www.foo.com"]',2,2)
          .pause(2000)
          .getCssProperty('a[href="http://www.foo.com"]', "background-color", function(results){
             console.log('color: ' + results);
       });
```

Comment: Do you get the same result if you move the browser.pause and .getCssProperty functionality out of the callback?  Also, are you getting any errors in the log?

Answer (score -1):

You won't see your physical mouse pointer move. Selenium doesn't move your mouse it just simulates the events in the browser.

Also, if your physical mouse is in the window, it'll mess with the events being generated and you won't see colors change properly, etc.

**The fix:** What you are doing above is correct, but you need to move your actual mouse to the bottom right-hand corner of the screen before the test starts.  Leave it there for the duration of the test.